# CORS issue during HTTP request from background service worker in Safari web extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Link to a repo with the Xcode project to test the issue: [Test CORS Issue](https://github.com/nick-kadutskyi/safari-ext-cors-issue)

This extension uses Manifest v3 and I have `example.com` in `host_permissions`

```json
"host_permissions": [
        "*://example.com/*"
    ]
```

When I run `fetch("https://example.com")` in `background.js` I get this error:

```
[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://example.com/ due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin safari-web-extension://e0b5d7c7-c079-484b-8825-44d261383cb6 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200 (example.com, line 0)
```

Tested in both Safari Version 16.0 (17614.1.25.9.10, 17614) and Safari Technology Preview Release 153 (Safari 16.0, WebKit 17615.1.4.1)

In the code I use `chrome` namespace (to test it in Chrome Browser) but I get the same issue with `browser` namespace.

If I run this extension without any change in Chrome Browser it works perfectly
(chrome://extensions/ → Load Unpacked)

**Is there a way to avoid CORS issues without altering server access control settings?**

Manifest v2 worked fine in this way.

**Update 1:**

The workaround for now to use background scripts (deprecated in v3) instead of background service worker.

Instead of this:

```json
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
```

Do this:

```json
 "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
```

**Update 2: How to make your extension work for both Chrome and Safari?**

Chrome supports only

```json
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
```

Safari supports both `service_worker` and `scripts` but when you use service_worker it has this CORS issue.

So the solution is to ship extension with different values in `background` field.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in Safari.

Comment: I noticed this as well. Using `service_worker` in Safari, it's broken with CORS, but background scripts still work. We already ship our extension with two different manifest files since Firefox also does not support `service_worker` yet, so we will also have to do the same for Safari. Sad times.

Comment: @NickKadutskyi - you should make an answer out of this to get you some stack points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No need for workaround

Fixed in Safari Tech Preview since Nov 5 2022
https://github.com/nick-kadutskyi/safari-ext-cors-issue/issues/1#event-8471562656

Fixed in Safari since 16.4

### Old workaround

The workaround for now to use background scripts (deprecated in v3) instead of background service worker.

Instead of this:

```json
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
```

Do this:

```json
 "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
```

**Update 2: How to make your extension work for both Chrome and Safari?**

Chrome supports only

```json
"background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
```

Safari supports both `service_worker` and `scripts` but when you use service_worker it has this CORS issue.

So the solution is to ship extension with different values in `background` field.

Answer (score 0):

This is now [fixed](https://webkit.org/blog/13966/webkit-features-in-safari-16-4/#safari-web-extensions) (and [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=247509)) in 16.4.

From: https://webkit.org/blog/13966/webkit-features-in-safari-16-4/#safari-web-extensions

```
Fixed CORS issue when doing fetch requests from a background service worker.
```